# Two versions of a function are not producing the same result

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, set

Assume that we have a `stack` filled with `0` and `1`. I want to change `mutation_rate_` many of the elements from `0` to `1` and vice versa. The elements that should be "mutated" are chosen randomly. I've written two function for this, that I will post below together with a test case, but one of them doesn't seem to work properly.

```
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using age_t = unsigned int;

std::stack<age_t>  mutate( std::stack<age_t>  genome_, age_t mutation_rate_ = 3){
    std::stack<age_t> final_stack;

    // Generate a set, whose elements are the positions at which we perforem the mutation.
    std::set<age_t> positions_to_switch;
    while(positions_to_switch.size() < mutation_rate_){
        positions_to_switch.insert(rand() % genome_.size());
    }

    // Create a counter to go through the stack amd iterator of the set.
    age_t cnt = 0;
    std::set<age_t>::iterator it= positions_to_switch.begin();

    while(genome_.empty()!=true){                               // Go through the whole genome_
        if(*it==cnt){                                           // check if current position in stack matches with
                                                                // element that needs mutation
            if(genome_.top()==1) final_stack.push(0);           // mutate
            else final_stack.push(1);
            ++it;                                               // go to next element that needs mutation
        }
        else{                                                   // if no mutation is needed
            final_stack.push(genome_.top());
        }
        genome_.pop();                                          // go to next element in stack
        ++cnt;                                                  // increase counter of stack
    }

    // final stack is in reverse order
    std::stack<age_t> res;
    while(!final_stack.empty()){
        res.push(final_stack.top());
        final_stack.pop();
    }
    return res;
};

std::stack<age_t> mutate_2( std::stack<age_t>  genome_, age_t mutation_rate_ = 3){
    std::stack<age_t> final_stack;

    std::vector<age_t> enumeration;
    age_t pos = 0;
    while(enumeration.size() < genome_.size()){
        enumeration.push_back(pos);
        ++pos;
    }
    pos = 0;

    auto rng = std::default_random_engine {};
    std::shuffle(enumeration.begin(), enumeration.end(), rng);

    std::vector<age_t> positions_to_switch;
    while(positions_to_switch.size() < mutation_rate_){
        positions_to_switch.push_back(enumeration[pos]);
        ++pos;
    }

    // Create a counter to go through the stack amd iterator of the set.
    age_t cnt = 0;
    std::vector<age_t>::iterator it= positions_to_switch.begin();

    while(genome_.empty()!=true){                           // Go through the whole genome_
        if(*it==cnt){                                       // check if current position in stack matches with
                                                            // element that needs mutation
            if(genome_.top()==1) final_stack.push(0);       // mutate
            else final_stack.push(1);
            ++it;                                           // go to next element that needs mutation
        }
        else{                                               // if no mutation is needed
            final_stack.push(genome_.top());
        }
        genome_.pop();                                      // go to next element in stack
        ++cnt;                                              // increase counter of stack
    }

    // final stack is in reverse order
    std::stack<age_t> res;
    while(!final_stack.empty()){
        res.push(final_stack.top());
        final_stack.pop();
    }
    return res;
};

int main(){

    std::stack<age_t> test_stack;
    test_stack.push(1);
    test_stack.push(0);
    test_stack.push(0);
    test_stack.push(0);
    test_stack.push(1);
    test_stack.push(1);

    std::stack<age_t> test_stack_copy = test_stack;
    std::stack<age_t> test_stack_copy_2 = test_stack;

    std::stack<age_t> res = mutate(test_stack);
    std::stack<age_t> res_2 = mutate_2(test_stack);


    std::cout << "Original Stack:\t";
    while(test_stack_copy_2.empty()!=true){
        std::cout << test_stack_copy_2.top();
        test_stack_copy_2.pop();
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "Muatet:\t\t";
    while(res.empty()!=true){
        std::cout << res.top();
        res.pop();
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "Muatet_2:\t";
    while(res_2.empty()!=true){
        std::cout << res_2.top();
        res_2.pop();
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Considering the test case `110001`, `mutate` returns `100111` and `mutate_2` returns `111101`, where I have set `mutation_rate_=3`, so three elements of the initial stack should have been changed. We can directly see that `mutate` has indeed changed three entries while `mutate_2` has only changed two of them... I'm pretty sure that this has something to do with how `set` and `vector` objects are handled, but I just can't find the error...

Comment: I didn't check the whole code and there may be other errors, but `*it==cnt` should be `it!=positions_to_switch.end() && *it==cnt`.

Comment: Did you check the contents of the set/vector `positions_to_switch`?

Comment: @MikeCAT yes, I printed them and the size and contet were sensible aka. the size was `muattion_rate_` and the contents were `usnigned int` numbers between zero and `genome.size()`

Comment: Have you tried doing a code walkthrough? The randomness can be tough to walk through, but you've printed out the contents of `positions_to_switch`, so that should not be a problem. (In case you need a test case, though, try `positions_to_switch = { 2, 3, 1 }`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you are using std::set that contains sorted elements (positions) in the ascending order.

In the second case the vector with positions is not sorted.

Include sorting of the vector

```
std::sort( positions_to_switch.begin(), positions_to_switch.end() );
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `std::set` is automatically sorted, but ones of `std::vector` isn't.

When the result of the shuffle is not ascending order (for example, `{2, 1, 3}`),
The small elements (`1` in the example) are ignored because the value is skipped while checking ther larger element (`2` in the example).

adding sorting

```
    std::sort(positions_to_switch.begin(), positions_to_switch.end());
```

after the element adding part

```
    std::vector<age_t> positions_to_switch;
    while(positions_to_switch.size() < mutation_rate_){
        positions_to_switch.push_back(enumeration[pos]);
        ++pos;
    }
```

will solve thie problem.

Another problem is that the iterator `it` may be after the last element when read in the tow `*it==cnt`.
Checking should bee inserted like `it!=positions_to_switch.end() && *it==cnt`.
(In this code, `it` won't be read when `it==positions_to_switch.end()` thanks to the short-circuit evaluation.)

Comment: Can you explain why the second case could potentially be an issue? I mean I obviously see how it can be a problem, but it shouldn't be possible for `it` to point to an element behind `positions_to_switch.end()` since I'm only increasing it when there is a match..